# Unable to display list items in custom View after adding items to list through code

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a custom list in MOSS 2010 that has a column type of Person/Group. I am storing AD username in that column. Also, I have created a view for the list that is filtering data based on the Person/Group column. All is good if I add/edit items in the list via MOSS.

However, I have created a web part that inserts the items in this list. After inserting the items in the list, the view does not display the items inserted to the list via webpart . However, if I edit the inserted record and save it again, it displays the record in the custom view.

Can you please help in this as I have wasted almost a day in fixing this and tried and tested all the obvious errors that I could like, checking of spaces/special charcters etc.

Comment: "view does not display the items correctly" - what does that mean?

Comment: @AshishPatel..I mean to say, it does not show the records at all in the custom view.I have edited the question

Comment: Can you share code snippet where you create list item? also when item is not displayed, how could you edit again? what's the criteria for the custom view?

Comment: I am editing the list item, by going in the All Items View of the list. Custom view displays the items where the Person/Group column = Current logged in user. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: Sorry, but would not be able to share code :(

Comment: @Nitesh, consider sharing only a small piece of code, where list item creation is shown. You can replace the actual strings and numbers with some dummy values.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly (because you didn't provide any code), but it looks like that you're putting some loose values into your Person/Group column. When you re-save item, SharePoint resolves the issue, probably by re-parsing the value.

The point is, that actually SharePoint validation is occasionally not very good and sometimes you're able to set some incorrect (bad-formatted) values through SharePoint Object Model.

Please, review your code intently, paying particular attention to the fragment where the Person/Group column is getting filled.

The right scenario for setting up a Person/Group field value will be:

1. First of all, you need to retrieve ID of the user
   if you have his login name, the best option will be to use
   SPWeb.EnsureUser method (it searches for the user, and if user
   with specified login was not found, it adds him to site).
2. Having user ID, and having SPListItem object instance, you
   should set the field value. The most prudent way to retrieve
   the right field is to use the field's guid.

The code will look something like this:

```
var loginName = // pass user login name here
var fieldGuid = // pass your field Guid here

var userId = SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName).ID;
listItem[fieldGuid] = userId;
// ... set other columns
listItem.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the detailed response. I agree with you and confirm I am using the same approach as mentioned by you. The only difference is only in this line: var userId = SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName);
listItem[fieldGuid] = userId;

Comment: I just tried changing var userId = SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName); to var userId = SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName).ID; but it is still not working :(

Comment: Then, the only approach I can recommend, is to use PowerShell or some simple console program to **dump** all the values from a problematic list item. So, you can run the program before and after re-saving the item, and then you will be able to compare the two dumps and find out what has changed.

Comment: ok..will try it now!

Comment: any example on how to dump the records from PS wud be gr8!